# Dependencies between PBIs in TFS Cloud (Scrum)

Tags: tfs, scrum, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I am filling the product backlog for a new product with user story PBIs. As I write, I realise that some PBIs are dependent on others being completed first. I cannot use the order of the backlog because it gets changed by others depending on client requirements. I want it to be obvious that one PBI depends upon another being completed first. Inter-PBI links are possible but it's not clear what a link between PBIs represents.

- What is the best way to get TFS 2012 (in the cloud) using the SCRUM template to represent PBI dependencies?
- Does anyone use hierarchical PBIs or tags for this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There is a WI link type for Predecessor/Successor.  This is how I typically do it.  It doesn't make it super-obvious, but the information is captured somebody just has to go to the WI Links tab to see it.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, I didn't see that in the links list. I'll leave it a week and if no-one can give a better option, I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: The fact that there is no "visualization" for these predecessor/successor relationships is unfortunate, but AFAIK there is no other way.  I've seen a TFS Work Item visualizer that attempts to model these (and parent/child), but was never really impressed.

Comment: You can always open the backlog in MS Project and the predecessor links should come over and you can use the Gantt chart to visualize <shudder>

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you get all of the people competing for priority in the backlog to appoint a single Backlog Owner who understand the dependencies ( sounds like you). That person can then order the backlog taking into account both customer priority and dependency.

I have in the past added a Customer priority field to the PBI & Bug to allow the Sales\Customer Services guys to order that field to their hearts content in excel.

That way they are not interfering with your order but still providing the influential and valuable customer order.